# PySpark Array Column of StructType - Filter on a column

Tags: pyspark

I am thinking of explicitly checking all columns that should be not null are not null, because from_json will force nullable.

I could write a case when statement and check
col("col1").isNull() or col("col2").isNull() then "InValid"

but how do I do the same for a column within an array?
After searching I came across filter function, but I am having trouble using it

expr('filter(col("selections"), column => column.?????.isNull())')

I cannot figure out how to use this filter function?

```
StructField("selections", ArrayType(StructType([ \
        StructField("selectionId", IntegerType(), False), \
        StructField("selectionIdXX", IntegerType(), False), \
    ])
```

the column I want to filter is within "selections" is named "selectionId"

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out how to use it.

so the filter returns a list of items that match the condition so I needed to get the count if count

```
(size(expr('filter(selections, x -> x.selectionId is null)')) > 0)
```

once that worked I figured exists works the same way.

```
expr('exists(selections, x -> x.selectionId is null)')
```

also without the expr function

```
exists(col("selections"), lambda x : x.selectionId.isNull())
```